# Программа запуска других программ

Tags: windows, c++

Здравствуйте!

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, наиболее компактное решение следующей задачи:
Необходимо написать программу на C++, которая будет запускать другие программы и интервалом в 10 секунд. Кол-во запускаемых программ не менее трех. Это должно быть простое консольное приложение. Среда MSVC 2010.

Зарание благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно что-то типа этого

```
_popen ("prog1", "r");
sleep (3);
_popen ("prog2", "r");
sleep (3);
```

и т.д.

Comment: или через system, как вариант, но тогда программы будут выполнятся, а потом уже запускаться следующие

Answer (score 0):

Под виндой самое простое WinExec. Первый аргумент командная строка, второй как показывать (SW_SHOW, SW_HIDE, SW_MAXIMIZE    и тд. При удаче функция возвращает значение больше 31
Пример:

```
void runIt(const char* path)
{
   if(WinExec(path,SH_HIDE)>31)//нужно показать окно программы (если оно есть) SW_SHOW
      Sleep(10*1000);
}
```